# Selenium infinite scrolling an next page | Python

Tags: python, selenium

my scrolling to the end of the page works, but i would like to follow the next pages too. I get the error:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Button__ButtonContainer-sc-3uaafx-0 .RVfyr .Pagination__PaginationButton-zvrf30-1 .iYAkvt"}

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

##### Web scraper for infinite scrolling page #####
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790")
time.sleep(2)  # Allow 2 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of 
the web
i = 1

while True:
# scroll one screen height each time
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, 
i=i))  
i += 1
time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
# update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled 
the page
scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
# Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
    break 
    
#Now locate the button & click on it   
next_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Button__ButtonContainer-sc-3uaafx-0 .RVfyr 
.Pagination__PaginationButton-zvrf30-1 .iYAkvt')
next_button.click()
```

.

```
##### Extract Datas #####
liste = []
doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
for xxx in doc.select(".jjQHPt"):

titel = xxx.select_one(".HOCpr").text
baujahr = xxx.select_one(".eizLtD").text
kilometer = xxx.select(".eizLtD")[1].text
try:
    preis = xxx.select_one(".fiVXiu").text
except:
    preis = 'None'    

print(titel)
print(preis)   
print("Baujahr: " + baujahr)
print("Kilometer: " + kilometer + " km")
print()
```

Comment: If you post the html element it would help with getting an answer.

Comment: https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790